# Job scheduling approximation

Tags: algorithms, approximation, arrays, subset-sum

In the course notes for Stanford MS&E-319: https://web.stanford.edu/class/msande319/lec1.pdf

Lemma 5 is given as:

> The approximation factor of the modified greedy [scheduling] algorithm is 4/3.

And gives the example:

> Note that 4/3 is essentially tight. Consider an instance with $m$ machines, $n = 2m+ 1$ jobs, $2m$ jobs of length
>   $m + 1, m + 2, · · · , 2m − 1$ and one job of length $m$.

does the above example have an error as a proof of lemma 5?

I have been thinking about it over a day.

Answer (score 1):

The instance in the example is "almost" the right one, however you are right that, as given, it does not prove tightness. The instance is missing **two more jobs of size $m$**.

After we include these two jobs, we have 2 jobs of each size from $2m-1$ to $m+1$ and 3 jobs of size $m$ (for $n=2m+1$ jobs in total, as stated).

Under the modified greedy algorithm, the maximum load will be $4m-1$. However, one can instead schedule a job of size $2m-i$ with a job of size $m+i$ for each $i=1,2,..., \lfloor  m/2 \rfloor$, and the remaining 3 jobs of size $m$ separately on the same machine. The maximum load will then be $3m$.

Comment: I took m = 2 , then should I have jobs 2,2,2,3 ?